# How to sort/order columns by data inside in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have data distributed in columns. I want to arrange columns in some order based on text inside.

Original data format:
[image]

Desired data format:
[image]

Specifically, I want to sort columns by data inside alphabetically and taking into account only first row. Other rows does not matter.

Comment: have you tried the sort/filter tool?

Comment: After selecting the data to be sorted, goto to Data ► Sort, and choose [Optons]. Use an Orientation: Sort left to right then you can choose Row 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is way to sort data from left to right. See the below screenshot.

[image]